# Объясните принцип работы

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Изучаю ассемблер. Не понимаю, как выполняется код. Объясните пожалуйста, что происходит, начиная с _start и заканчивая loop add_loop. Я не понимаю принципа работы.

```
section .text
   global _start        
 
_start:                 
 
   mov     esi, 4       
   mov     ecx, 5      
   clc
add_loop:  
   mov  al, [num1 + esi]
   adc  al, [num2 + esi]
   aaa
   pushf
   or   al, 30h
   popf
    
   mov  [sum + esi], al
   dec  esi
   loop add_loop
    
   mov  edx,len         
   mov  ecx,msg         
   mov  ebx,1           
   mov  eax,4           
   int  0x80            
    
   mov  edx,5           
   mov  ecx,sum         
   mov  ebx,1           
   mov  eax,4           
   int  0x80            
    
   mov  eax,1           
   int  0x80            
 
section .data
msg db 'The Sum is:',0xa    
len equ $ - msg         
num1 db '12345'
num2 db '23456'
sum db '     '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, добавил комментарии к командам:

```
_start:                 
 
   mov     esi, 4 ; инициализация рабочего разряда в числах (единицы)
   mov     ecx, 5 ; инициализация переменной цикла
   clc            ; сброс флага переноса CF
add_loop:  
   mov  al, [num1 + esi] ; записываем цифру из выбранного разряда
   adc  al, [num2 + esi] ; сложение двух цифр c добавлением значения флага переноса CF
   aaa          ; увеличение значение регистра AH на 1
   pushf        ; записать в стек регистр FLAGS
   or   al, 30h ; получение значения ASCII
   popf         ; возвращаем значения регистра FLAGS из стека
    
   mov  [sum + esi], al ; записываем значения ASCII в разряд результата
   dec  esi             ; декремент разряда числа 
   loop add_loop        ; декрементим CX и возвращаемся к началу цикла
```

Та же логика на С:

```cpp
int main() {
    char first[] = "12345";
    char second[] =  "23456";
    char result[] = "     ";
    char sum;
    char flag = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum = first[i] + second[i] - 0x30 + flag;
        if (sum > '9') {
            sum = sum - 0xA;
            flag = 1;          
        } else {
            flag = 0;
        }
        result[i] = sum;
    }
    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: По моему, aaa это Adjust After Addition. Это инструкция ACII. А так, спасибо, я вроде как понял

Comment: А ещё, что такое флаг переноса?

Comment: [флаг CF wiki](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: Окей, спасибо, вы сильно помогли мне